# Почему inline-block'и смещаются?

Tags: css, вёрстка, html, frontend

Почему блоки в разнобой? Почему так? И как сделать так, чтобы они были на одном уровне?

[image: Картинка]

```css
.box {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  border: 1px solid;
  margin: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="panel">
  <div class="box">
    testtext
  </div>

  <div class="box"></div>

  <div class="box">
    <img src="kevin.jpg" style="max-width: 40px;" />
  </div>

  <div class="box">
    <img src="kevin.jpg" style="max-width: 60px;" />
  </div>

  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

У `display: inline-block;` по-умолчанию выравнивание по базовой линии - `vertical-align: baseline;`

Поэтому стоит задать `vertical-align: middle;` или `vertical-align: top;` чтобы блоки расположились в одну линию:

```css
.box{
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
    border: 1px solid;
    margin: 5px;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<div class="panel">
        <div class="box">
            testtext            
        </div>

        <div class="box"></div>

        <div class="box">
            <img src="kevin.jpg" style="max-width: 40px;"/>
        </div>

        <div class="box">
            <img src="kevin.jpg" style="max-width: 60px;"/>
        </div>

        <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Работает! Cпасибо!